# Wicket Composite Behavior

Tags: wicket

I have created a composite behavior - basically two AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehaviors in one (onBlur and onKeyUp). It is available here : http://tny.cz/0ff0ead2

When rendering a component to which this Behavior has been added, I get an exception stating that "[the] Behavior _ was not registered with this component". The exception occurs when the `blur.onComponentTag()`method is called from within the behavior's`onComponentTag()`.

Does anyone have any idea why this is? I should mention that I am using Wicket 1.4.21.

Thanks,

A

Comment: Try to replace `blur.bind(component)` and `keyUp.bind(component)` with `component.add (blur, keyUp)`.

Comment: Great! That worked. Thanks @MichaelZhavzharov. Would you like to move your comment to an answer so that I can upvote it and mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your composite behavior's `#bind()` method you call another `#bind()` methods for your `blur` and `keyUp`, but, as @Sven already mentioned, calling this method not enough to do the trick, because it creates link to `component` for `behaviors`, but `component` still don't know anything about them.

When you call `component.add(behaviors)`, there are internal calls for `#bind()` methods of every behavior. And this is what you actually need.

---

So, just replace :

```
blur.bind(component);
keyUp.bind(component);
```

by following:

```
component.add (blur, keyUp);
```

Comment: Well I'd really like to give you both the answer but I saw Michael's comment first. My thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

The exception originates in RequestCycle#urlFor():

```
public final CharSequence urlFor(final Component component, final IBehavior behaviour,
    final RequestListenerInterface listener)
{
    int index = component.getBehaviorsRawList().indexOf(behaviour);
    if (index == -1)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Behavior " + this +
            " was not registered with this component: " + component.toString());
    }
```

As Michael already commented, your wrapped behaviors have to be added to the component, just calling #bind() is not enough.